# SilverStripe. Search by date-range in ModelAdmin

Tags: search, silverstripe, datefield, modeladmin

I have date-property in my DataObject.

How can I search by date-range in ModelAdmin?

For example: "search all items where date is more than 2007-13-01 and less than 2007-17-01"
or "search all items where date is between 2007-13-01 and 2007-17-01"

For now I can search only with GreaterTranFilter or with LessThanFilter, but not with both.

```
class MyObject extends DataObject {
    private static $db = [
        "Date" => "Date",
    ];
    private static $summary_fields = [
        "Date" => "Date",
    ];

    private static $searchable_fields = [
        "Date" => [
            "field" => "DateField",
            "filter" => "GreaterThanFilter",
            "title" => 'Date from ...'
        ],
    ];
}
```

Additionally search field must use a calendar(datepicker)

```
DateField:
  default_config:
    showcalendar: true
```

Can you give an example how to search by date-range?

Comment: a quick google search showed me https://gist.github.com/dljoseph/de44dce46b2194661381 which might help you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a `WithinRangeFilter`, but it's not going to get you very far if you're using configuration only. This is something you really need to implement procedurally.

Add the range filters by overloading `getSearchContext()`, then overload `getList()` and check the `q` request param for the date ranges, and apply them to the list.

```
public function getSearchContext()
{
    $context = parent::getSearchContext();
    $context->getFields()->push(DateField::create('q[Start]','Start'));
    $context->getFields()->push(DateField::create('q[End]','End'));

    return $context;
}

public function getList()
{
    $list = parent::getList();
    $params = $this->getRequest()->requestVar('q');

    $filters = [];
    if(isset($params['Start'])) {
        $filters['Date:LessThanOrEqual'] = $params['Start'];
    }
    if(isset($params['End'])) {
        $filters['Date:GreaterThanOrEqual'] = $params['End'];
    }

    return $list->filter($filters);
}
```