# How to generate a custom CSV export?

Tags: php, silverstripe

I have a page called `EventPage` that I am managing via a Model admin. Also using Catalog manager: https://github.com/littlegiant/silverstripe-catalogmanager

Question is I need to be able to export all the expired events (And all of the fields).

I have an `'EndDate' => 'Date',` field on the `EventPage`.

So I want to only show EventPages in my CSV export where the EndDate is GreaterThanOrEqual to todays date e.g Expired.

The following generates an CSV export button, but currently it is exporting all the fields, where as I want to filter it so we only show the expired events.

How do I go about this?

```
<?php

class EventAdmin extends CatalogPageAdmin {

    public $showImportForm = false;

    private static $managed_models = array(
        'EventPage',
        'EventCategory',
        'EventSubmission',
    );

    private static $url_segment = 'events';

    private static $menu_title = 'Events';


    public function getEditForm($id = null, $fields = null) {

        $form = parent::getEditForm($id, $fields);

        $gridFieldName = 'EventPage';
        $gridField = $form->Fields()->fieldByName($gridFieldName);

        if ($gridField) {
            $gridField->getConfig()->addComponent(new GridFieldExportButton());
        }

        return $form;
    }


}
```

Comment: so you want two things? CSV export with only the fields you want AND only showing a certain amount of `EventPages` on your Gridfield? I answered the first question, but let me know if I understand correctly...

Answer (score 3):

We can create a custom export button to filter the list of items before exporting them.

First we create a `GridFieldExportExpiredEventsButton` which extends `GridFieldExportButton`. This is a complete copy of the current SilverStripe 3.5 `generateExportFileData` function but with an added `filterByCallback` on the `$items` list to filter items that have an `EndDate < date('Y-m-d')`.

```
class GridFieldExportExpiredEventsButton extends GridFieldExportButton {

    public function getHTMLFragments($gridField) {
        $button = new GridField_FormAction(
            $gridField,
            'export',
            'Export expired events',
            'export',
            null
        );
        $button->setAttribute('data-icon', 'download-csv');
        $button->addExtraClass('no-ajax action_export');
        $button->setForm($gridField->getForm());
        return array(
            $this->targetFragment => '<p class="grid-csv-button">' . $button->Field() . '</p>',
        );
    }

    public function generateExportFileData($gridField) {
        $separator = $this->csvSeparator;
        $csvColumns = $this->getExportColumnsForGridField($gridField);
        $fileData = '';
        $member = Member::currentUser();

        if($this->csvHasHeader) {
            $headers = array();

            // determine the CSV headers. If a field is callable (e.g. anonymous function) then use the
            // source name as the header instead
            foreach($csvColumns as $columnSource => $columnHeader) {
                $headers[] = (!is_string($columnHeader) && is_callable($columnHeader)) ? $columnSource : $columnHeader;
            }

            $fileData .= "\"" . implode("\"{$separator}\"", array_values($headers)) . "\"";
            $fileData .= "\n";
        }

        //Remove GridFieldPaginator as we're going to export the entire list.
        $gridField->getConfig()->removeComponentsByType('GridFieldPaginator');

        $items = $gridField->getManipulatedList();

        $items = $items->filterByCallback(function($item) {
            // The following line modifies what items are filtered. Change this to change what items are filtered
            return $item->EndDate < date('Y-m-d');
        });

        // @todo should GridFieldComponents change behaviour based on whether others are available in the config?
        foreach($gridField->getConfig()->getComponents() as $component){
            if($component instanceof GridFieldFilterHeader || $component instanceof GridFieldSortableHeader) {
                $items = $component->getManipulatedData($gridField, $items);
            }
        }

        foreach($items->limit(null) as $item) {
            if(!$item->hasMethod('canView') || $item->canView($member)) {
                $columnData = array();

                foreach($csvColumns as $columnSource => $columnHeader) {
                    if(!is_string($columnHeader) && is_callable($columnHeader)) {
                        if($item->hasMethod($columnSource)) {
                            $relObj = $item->{$columnSource}();
                        } else {
                            $relObj = $item->relObject($columnSource);
                        }

                        $value = $columnHeader($relObj);
                    } else {
                        $value = $gridField->getDataFieldValue($item, $columnSource);

                        if($value === null) {
                            $value = $gridField->getDataFieldValue($item, $columnHeader);
                        }
                    }

                    $value = str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), "\n", $value);
                    $columnData[] = '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $value) . '"';
                }

                $fileData .= implode($separator, $columnData);
                $fileData .= "\n";
            }

            if($item->hasMethod('destroy')) {
                $item->destroy();
            }
        }

        return $fileData;
    }
}
```

The extra line that we have added that filters the export items is:

```
return $item->EndDate < date('Y-m-d');
```

Alter this to alter the list of items that are exported. I have set this to only return items which have an `EndDate` that is in the past. Change this as you need.

We then add this export button to our grid field in our event model admin:

```
class EventAdmin extends CatalogPageAdmin {

    private static $managed_models = array(
        'EventPage'
    );

    public function getEditForm($id = null, $fields = null) {
        $form = parent::getEditForm($id);
        if ($this->modelClass == 'EventPage') {
            $gridField = $form->Fields()->fieldByName($this->modelClass);
            $gridField->getConfig()->removeComponentsByType('GridFieldExportButton');
            $gridField->getConfig()->addComponent(new GridFieldExportExpiredEventsButton('buttons-before-left'));
        }

        return $form;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks very promising, a couple of issues, first it is giving this error: `[Recoverable Error] Argument 1 passed to GridFieldConfig::removeComponent() must implement interface GridFieldComponent, null given` - I commented out this line: `$gridField->getConfig()->removeComponent($gridField->getConfig()->getComponentByType('GridFieldExportButton'));` - Which gets rid of the error however upon clicking the "Export expired events" button it then only exports 3 items where as it should be exports approx 30 items atm. Thank you for you help so far :)

Comment: I have modified the `removeComponent` line so that hopefully it works for you. I have also noted the line of code that modifies the item list. Modify this line to meet your needs. In my example code I have this line set to `return $item->EndDate < date('Y-m-d');`, which well return only items which have an `EndDate` that is in the past.

Comment: Thanks for that, its working now without getting that error, however it is still only returning 2x results within the CSV where it should be returning alot more. Your code within the `filterByCallback` should work as you say. Somethings not quite right, if i run a mysql query like: `SELECT * FROM EventPage
  WHERE EndDate < curdate()` - I get 42 results back:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/dykhtx7duw25w4j/Screenshot%202017-03-03%2010.41.36.png?dl=0.

Answer (score 1):

This was originally two answers...

## To limit the fields

Have you had a look at the `GridFieldExportButton` class ?
The constructor

```
    /**
 * @param string $targetFragment The HTML fragment to write the button into
 * @param array $exportColumns The columns to include in the export
 */
public function __construct($targetFragment = "after", $exportColumns = null) {
    $this->targetFragment = $targetFragment;
    $this->exportColumns = $exportColumns;
}
```

So you should be able to pass `$exportColumns` as an argument.

in your code that would be

```
        if ($gridField) {
        $gridField->getConfig()->addComponent(new GridFieldExportButton("after", ["field1", "field2"]));
    }
```

OR - EVEN BETTER SOLUTION

you can define your summary fields on `EventPage` as such

```
private static $summary_fields = ["FIeld1", "Field2"];
```

Then make sure your flush and it should use that as fields.

## To filter which items to export in your CSV

So in this case, I think you should create a new class that extends `GridFieldExportButton` (maybe called `EventPageCSVExportButton` or something) and override the methods you want. In your case it would probably be `generateExportFileData()`, just do a check in the loop and exclude data you don't want.

Then use that new class in your EventAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at the `GridFieldExportButton` class ? 
The constructor

```
    /**
 * @param string $targetFragment The HTML fragment to write the button into
 * @param array $exportColumns The columns to include in the export
 */
public function __construct($targetFragment = "after", $exportColumns = null) {
    $this->targetFragment = $targetFragment;
    $this->exportColumns = $exportColumns;
}
```

So you should be able to pass `$exportColumns` as an argument.

in your code that would be

```
        if ($gridField) {
        $gridField->getConfig()->addComponent(new GridFieldExportButton("after", ["field1", "field2"]));
    }
```

OR - EVEN BETTER SOLUTION

you can define your summary fields on `EventPage` as such

```
private static $summary_fields = ["FIeld1", "Field2"];
```

Then make sure your flush and it should use that as fields.

Comment: Hey, not quite what im after, so I want to export all the fields but only of the expired events. So I need a way to add some logic that says 'if EndDate:GreaterThanOrEqual than todays date' generate a list so we end up with just the expired events instead of all events. Hope that makes sense :)

Comment: You have to filter the list in ModelAdmin before you export it. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/42450800/4137738 as a start. You need to overwrite your ModelAdmin's `getList()` method.

Comment: Can you combine your answers into one?

Comment: Years later, in 4.6.1 I find the column array when creating the GridFieldExportButton needs to be associative otherwise I get columns but no data.